# Sentinel and Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, authentication, sentinel

I cant make Sentinel work. I don't know what to do anymore, i tried everything, hopefully someone else have some advice.
Problem is in online middleware where check method is false...

EDIT: i found out problem is sessions are not working in middleware, still no solution tho

EDIT2: looks like its permisions, i am on ubuntu, i have run same code with xampp on win10 and everything works fine, still no solution for ubuntu

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {

Route::get('/',          ['as' => 'index'    , 'uses' => 'UserController@index']);
Route::post('login',     ['as' => 'login'    , 'uses' => 'UserController@login']);
Route::post('register',  ['as' => 'register' , 'uses' => 'UserController@register']);
Route::get('logout',    ['as' => 'logout'   , 'uses' => 'UserController@logout']);

Route::group(['prefix' => 'viva' , 'middleware' => ['online']], function () {
    Route::get('/',     ['as' => 'dashboard'    , 'uses' => 'VivaController@dashboard']);
});
});
```

login method

```
public function login(){
    $data = Input::all();

    $credentials = [
        'email'    => $data["username"],
        'password' => $data["password"],
    ];

    $user = Sentinel::authenticate($credentials);

    if (!empty($user)){
        Sentinel::login($user);
        //dd(Sentinel::check()); //---> this gives logged user...
        return Redirect::route('dashboard');
    }
    else{
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['fail', 'Neuspjela prijava! Molimo pokušajte ponovo.']);
    }


}
```

online.php Middleware

```
 class online
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next )
{
    dd(Sentinel::check()); //---> this is always false


    if (Sentinel::check())
    {
        return Redirect::route('dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::route('index')->withErrors(['fail', 'Nemate prava na pristup ovim stranicama!']);
    }

    return $next($request);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For session, I believe you might need these permissions.

*Note: assumption that Laravel is installed at `/var/www/laravel`*

```
cd /var/www/laravel
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```